# remove all inherited css properties

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, styled-components

I have a popup that will be added to websites via javascript. I have no clue on what sort of styles will be applied on these websites.

Example website has the current styles added:

```
h3 {
color: blue;
border: 5px solid red;
font-size: 24px;
}
```

My Popup which is added to the body of the website has:

```
 PopupText = styled.h3`
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
`;
```

This means that **font size** and **color** are what i've declared but the border will be added regardless, is there any way to remove the added extra css properties, or to protect from additional styling added by the website?

To sum up, I want my popup to look the same, no matter where it is added. As of right now, when i add it to a website it changes depending on what styling is on the website

Comment: Can you make your code into a working snippet we can run because the answer given by @ArashHatami (all: unset;) looks as though it should work and I cannot reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `all` attribute like this :

```css
.class {
  all: unset;
}
```

Check it [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade/#all-shorthand)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I've tried this method but it seems not to work :( the extra properties are still added

Comment: Are you putting all:unset as the first property setting in your PopupText definition?

Comment: I've placed a div wrapper and added the all unset property to it

Comment: That's not good enough if h3 is having specific styles applied. You need to put all: unset in your h3 styling as the first line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use **iframe** tag for wrap

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:not()` selector to achieve that: If your popup element has a class (which is probably the case) you can modify your regular css rule for `h3` as follows:

```
*:not(.yourpopupclass) h3 {
  color: blue;
  border: 5px solid red;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

This will affect any `h3` element that is a child element of anything (i.e. also of `body`), except if it's a child of an element that has class `.yourpopupclass` (i.e. is inside your popup).

The same woud be possible with an ID if the popup has no class, but an ID.

Comment: Im not sure this is the right way, I am adding a popup which has bundled css into any given website I dont have access to the website nor do i know what styles are being applied, I want to achieve the same look of my popup no matter where it is added

Comment: Ah okay, if you can't modify the original CSS of the website, using this method won't be possible. The only other way I could recommend – for your popup h3 – would be to add css settings for *all* properties you can think of (i.e. font size, style, color, weight, line-height, border, padding, margin, background etc.), maybe even adding `!important` to each one, in order to overwrite anything there could possible be inherited from the website's stylesheet.